# How to avoid hibernate insert empty string to my feild?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a Mysql table with a field name "password", I have set this field is NOT NULL in mysql.

but hibernate always insert empty string to my table.

so, I wander if there is a way to config hibernate treat empty string as null and let mysql throw an error that the field is not allow to be NULL.

Comment: I think your default value in the object is '' not null. if it is null, an exception should pop up.

Comment: You should be checking this a long time before you even get to the insert statement.

Comment: yes, the form send an empty post item, my app just put this to hibernate, and MySQL see empty string, and don't translate it to null

Comment: After all, shouldn't there be other restrictions, like password must contain special character, must be 8 chars long, etc.  Do you want to allow users to make a password of "a"?

Comment: Yes, I should validate my data in MVC layer. just use hibernate validator for dubble check. tnx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a constraint to your password field by using the [@NotBlank annotation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/api/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/NotBlank.html).

Comment: I'm using xml config file now. is there a eqivelent?

Comment: I've never done that, but here's [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-xmlconfiguration.html#d0e2024) on the topic.